# What are the main reasons for using an interface in the decorator design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```java
interface Dress {
  public void assemble();
}

class BasicDress implements Dress {
  @Override public void assemble() {
    System.out.println("Basic Dress Features");
  }
}

class DressDecorator implements Dress {
  protected Dress dress;

  public DressDecorator(Dress c) {
    this.dress = c;
  }

  @Override public void assemble() {
    this.dress.assemble();
  }
}

class SportyDress extends DressDecorator {
  public SportyDress(Dress c) {
    super(c);
  }
  
  @Override public void assemble() {
    super.assemble();
    System.out.println("Adding Sporty Dress Features");
  }
}

class FancyDress extends DressDecorator {
  public FancyDress(Dress c) {
    super(c);
  }
  
  @Override
  public void assemble() {
    super.assemble();
    System.out.println("Adding Fancy Dress Features");
  }
}

public class DecoratorPatternTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dress sportyDress = new SportyDress(new BasicDress());
    sportyDress.assemble();
    System.out.println();
    
    Dress fancyDress = new FancyDress(new BasicDress());
    fancyDress.assemble();
    System.out.println();  
  }
}
```

Why do we need an interface in the decorator design pattern?

Comment: Coding to interfaces is generally a good pattern to follow. It's primarily used to ensure the code has flexibility in implementation. It meets the SOLID principles by ensuring that it follows O, L and D aspects of it. It also allows for testing through the use of mocks and stubs.

Comment: Are you asking about the `Dress` interface?

Comment: Yes. What would happen If delete this interface? Could I be to design a decorator design pattern without interface?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have in mind some more complex logic that justifies that class structure, I think you have there 1 level of redundancy at a conceptual level.
DressDecorator is a generic that is subclassed by FancyDress and SportyDress. That's fine.
Then you might need an interface to implement some logic that needs to be common to other classes as well. But calling it Dress may be too specific, something like Wear could be more general. And it could be implemented by other wearables. In this case, I don't see what you would need that BasicWhatever for.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for using an interface in the decorator pattern is that it is more flexible than using a class hierarchy.

Your code wants to use `Dress` instances without caring whether it is working with a `BasicDress`, a `SportyDress` or some other decorated `Dress` instance.

In Java you have two possibilities to implement such a design:

- make `Dress` a (possibly abstract) class and extend it in `BasicDress` and `DressDecorator`
- make `Dress` an interface and implement it in `BasicDress` and `DressDecorator`

Of these two options the option to make `Dress` an interface is more flexible because this means that `DressDecorator` could extend some other, unrelated class.

---

Without a common interface / base class for `BasicDress` and `DressDecorator` you have to decide between supporting only `BasicDress` or supporting only `DressDecorator`.

For example following code is only possible if `BasicDress` and `DressDecorator` share a common interface or base class:

```
public class DecoratorPatternTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dress basicDress = new BasicDress();
    useDress(basicDress);

    Dress sportyDress = new SportyDress(new BasicDress());
    useDress(sportyDress);
    
    Dress fancyDress = new FancyDress(new BasicDress());
    useDress(fancyDress);

    Dress sportyFancyDress = new SportyDress(new FancyDress(new BasicDress()));
    useDress(sportyFancyDress);
  }

  private static void useDress(Dress dress) {
    dress.assemble();
    System.out.println();  
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, my question was what would happen If delete this interface? Could I be to design a decorator design pattern without an interface if SportyDress and FancyDress classes extend DressDecorator class?

Comment: @FahinMiah I've updated my answer with an example of what would no longer work if you drop the `Dress` interface.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator pattern can be used to extend (decorate) the functionality of a certain object statically, or in some cases at run-time, independently of other instances of the same class, provided some groundwork is done at design time. This is achieved by designing a new Decorator class that wraps the original class.